# Flutter: Using NumberFormat in TextInputFormatter

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to use `NumberFromatter` in `TextInputFormatter` but when I try to use it, it completely messed up! This is my `TextInputFormatter` implementation code:

```
class NumericTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if(newValue.text.length > 0) {
      int num = int.parse(newValue.text.replaceAll(',', ''));
      final f = new NumberFormat("#,###");
      return newValue.copyWith(text: f.format(num));
    } else { 
      return newValue.copyWith(text: '');
    }
  }
}
```

So when I add this formatter to a `TextField` and try to type 1 to 9, what I expect to see is something like: `123,456,789`

But this is what shows in `TextField`:

```
1
12
123
1,234
12,354 <- this is where it starts
123,564
1,235,674
12,356,874 <- and it happends again
```

It seems that cursor moves after adding one , character. So can anyone helps me with this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is because after you format the value you are adding a new char but the text selection remains at the same position, one char less, this cause an expected behavior

You can modify your `TextInputFormatter` like this:

**Fixed to support all locales and to remember cursor position**

```dart
class NumericTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (newValue.text.isEmpty) {
      return newValue.copyWith(text: '');
    } else if (newValue.text.compareTo(oldValue.text) != 0) {
      final int selectionIndexFromTheRight =
          newValue.text.length - newValue.selection.end;
      final f = NumberFormat("#,###");
      final number =
          int.parse(newValue.text.replaceAll(f.symbols.GROUP_SEP, ''));
      final newString = f.format(number);
      return TextEditingValue(
        text: newString,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
            offset: newString.length - selectionIndexFromTheRight),
      );
    } else {
      return newValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works great! But when user tries to edit one character in middle of string then cursor moves to the end of the string. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: @diegoveloper, solution worked out fine. Even when tried the situation of deleting a middle character and the cursor moves as expected.

Comment: Is this in a pub.dev package?

Comment: Is there a way to get the unformatted value back during processing later?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer and for people from Europe looking for a quick fix

```
class NumericTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    final currencySymbol = '€';
    if (newValue.text.isEmpty || newValue.text.trim() == currencySymbol) {
      return newValue.copyWith(text: '');
    } else if (newValue.text.compareTo(oldValue.text) != 0) {
      var selectionIndexFromTheRight =
          newValue.text.length - newValue.selection.end;
      final f =
          NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'de', decimalDigits: 0, symbol: '');
      var num = int.parse(newValue.text.replaceAll(RegExp('[^0-9]'), ''));
      final newString = '$currencySymbol ' + f.format(num).trim();
      return TextEditingValue(
        text: newString,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(
            offset: newString.length - selectionIndexFromTheRight),
      );
    } else {
      return newValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how can we change the separator? I want the separator to be comma ',' instead of dot