# Why Android not able to show correct formatted Text in TextField while iOS does?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Minimal code:**

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyPage()));

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _controller = TextEditingController(text: "");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(44.0),
        child: Center(
          child: TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            onChanged: (string) {
              string = string.replaceAll(RegExp(","), "");
              string = _formattedString(string);
              _controller.text = string;
              _controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: string.length));
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

   _formattedString(string) {
    final format = NumberFormat.decimalPattern();
    return format.format(int.parse(string));
  }
}
```

---

Run this code, in both Android and iOS, enter number like `123456789`, in Android it prints some weird sequence however it does work in iOS. Can anybody tell me what's wrong in the code?

**Android output**

[image]

---

**iOS output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't want another dependency in your project, give this a try:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyPage()));

class NumericTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    if (newValue.text.length == 0) {
      return newValue.copyWith(text: '');
    } else if (newValue.text.compareTo(oldValue.text) != 0) {
      int selectionIndexFromTheRight = newValue.text.length - newValue.selection.end;
      final f = new NumberFormat("#,###");
      int num = int.parse(newValue.text.replaceAll(f.symbols.GROUP_SEP, ''));
      final newString = f.format(num);
      return new TextEditingValue(
        text: newString,
        selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: newString.length - selectionIndexFromTheRight),
      );
    } else {
      return newValue;
    }
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final _controller = TextEditingController(text: "");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(44.0),
        child: Center(
          child: TextField(
            controller: _controller,
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            inputFormatters: [NumericTextFormatter()],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Credit goes to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51739086/5235984

Comment: Thank you but can you tell me why the code works fine in iOs

Comment: Without diving too deep into, you are using both onChanged and TextEditingController. You should be using one of them: [flutter.dev](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes) `With Flutter, you have two options: 1) Supply an onChanged() callback to a TextField or a TextFormField. 2) Use a TextEditingController. ` 
When I ran your code on my emulator the position wouldn't even go to the last character after comma was added, so I'm guessing you've made some sort of race condition which gives different results based not only on OS but speed / model of the device as well.

Comment: I'll upvote your answer because of the explanation given in comment, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

> dependencies: 
>     flutter_masked_text: ^0.8.0

1. Create your mask controller
2. Set controller to your text field:

`class MyPage extends StatelessWidget {
    var _controller = new MaskedTextController(mask: '000,000,000,00');`

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(44.0),
            child: Center(
                child: TextField(controller: _controller)
            )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm not looking for a package. Thanks for your efforts though.